# Creating random multi-index dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to create random multi-index dataframes in Pandas? (ideally with index and column names using strings, and contents holding numbers)

Perhaps more difficult, is there any way to parameterize the creation of such random dataframe by the number of index levels and column levels? For example, `create_random_multi_index_dataframe(3,2)` would create a `df` with an index with three levels and columns with two levels.

Comment: No drop-in mechanism, no. But you can create one yourself pretty easily with `np.random`, the dataframe constructor, and the `set_index` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really part of the exposed API, but the following imports a function for creating random DataFrames.

```
from pandas.util.testing import makeCustomDataframe
```

You can dig through the docstring, but for example, to make a DataDrame with 2 levels for both rows and columns.

```
makeCustomDataframe(10, 10, c_idx_nlevels=2, r_idx_nlevels=2)
```